# Is there a limit on record updates for MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a PHP script to do some color conversions from  Hexadecimal to RGB and HSL values and store them in a database. My current dataset is the entire Pantone Solid Coated color book which is 1341 colors. I have the Hexadecimal values already in there.

From there I accessed the database and took the Hex value and did the two conversions and then stored them back in the table.

I am getting no errors, but the process seems to stop at record 499 for the updates even though the echo of all the values I did for testing show the calculations being applied to all 1341 colors.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
// SQL Server Login Info Removed
$sql_connection = new mysqli($sql_server, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_database);

if ($sql_connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $sql_connection->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM coated";
$result = $sql_connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $colorname = $row["mapName"];
        $hexvalue = $row["hex"];

        if ($row["rgb"] == '') {
            $rgbvalue = hex2rgb($hexvalue);
        } else {
            $rgbvalue = $row["rgb"];
        }
        if ($row["hsl"] == '') {
            $hslvalue = hex2hsl($hexvalue);
        } else {
            $hslvalue = $row["hsl"];
        }

        //echo "Color: " . $row["mapName"] . " | " . $rgbvalue . " | " . $hslvalue . "<br>";

        $wrt_query = "UPDATE coated SET hex='".$hexvalue."', rgb='".$rgbvalue."', hsl='".$hslvalue."' WHERE mapName='".$colorname."'";
        if ($sql_connection->query($wrt_query) === true) {
            echo "Record for " . $colorname . " updated <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record for " . $colorname . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

The data comes from a CSV file. Here is a excerpt:

```
pantone-Yellow-C,#fedd00
pantone-Yellow-012-C,#ffd700
pantone-Orange-021-C,#fe5000
pantone-Warm-Red-C,#f9423a
pantone-Red-032-C,#ef3340
pantone-Rubine-Red-C,#ce0058
pantone-Rhodamine-Red-C,#e10098
pantone-Purple-C,#bb29bb
pantone-Violet-C,#440099
pantone-Blue-072-C,#10069f
pantone-Reflex-Blue-C,#001489
pantone-Process-Blue-C,#0085ca
pantone-Green-C,#00ab84
pantone-Black-C,#2d2926
pantone-Yellow-0131-C,#f2f0a1
pantone-Red-0331-C,#fcaebb
pantone-Magenta-0521-C,#f1b2dc
pantone-Violet-0631-C,#bf9bde
pantone-Blue-0821-C,#74d1ea
pantone-Green-0921-C,#9de7d7
pantone-Black-0961-C,#9e978e
...
pantone-Black-2-C,#332f21
pantone-Black-3-C,#212721
pantone-Black-4-C,#31261d
pantone-Black-5-C,#3e2b2e
pantone-Black-6-C,#101820
pantone-Black-7-C,#3d3935
```

Comment: when you store the data in DB it takes a little more time than usual as it is not just I/O operation, I think you have a time out, either you should do it in small chunks (which is a better practice) or increase timeout in php.ini file

Comment: Did you original request get all the rows, or are they paged or something.  There is not a limit to stop you from posting thousands of updates.  It is more likely you are missing records in your code, or had a time-out or other database error abort your script.

Comment: Is `mapname` a unique index?

Comment: @StevenScott The original request is all rows

Comment: @Octopi It is in terms of the data but not set as such in the db. The table was created using a CSV import.

Comment: @NishchalGautam How would I chunk this up then?

Comment: can we have the csv?

Comment: @Octopi Added an excerpt.

Comment: what is record #499 in the csv?

Comment: @belinus nice, thanks

Comment: @Octopi pantone-512-C,#833177

Comment: Could you check that the mapName column wasnt accidently truncated?
Can you give me its length by looking at the database create statement?

Comment: @Octopi The length was set to 23 when the CSV was imported to create the table.

Comment: Which is consistent with the longest field, `pantone-Rhodamine-Red-C` so that should be fine.

Comment: What's your evidence that the process stops at record 449? Can you show us the results of a `SELECT * ...` for one of the rows that you believe isn't being updated? There are plenty of things that could be the cause, e.g. if the columns you're updating have `NULL`s rather than empty strings in them, then your code will appear to do nothing for those rows.

Comment: Don't execute queries inside loops.

Comment: @Strawberry Then where would I iterate through all the conversions and store them? I know it is not best practice but this script is really designed to be run once and never again because it only needs to run once and then it's set. In this instance I was able to work around the problem and I still got my SASS map files which was what I was going for ultimate. But I am still curious as to why this went wrong and how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: @MattGibson Looking at the database rows. I ran the script again and this time it got to 589 before it conked out. I ran `SELECT * FROM coated LIMIT 5 OFFSET 588`. The first row has values in all columns but everything below that only has the _nameMap_ and _hex_ values. _rgb_ and _hsl_ are empty until the end of the table. When I was writing the script though, I had an echo statement that emulated what was going to happen in the database and it went through all 1341 rows.

Comment: Typically, you would build the query inside the loop, then execute it once afterwards.

Comment: @belinus you could add a ; to the end of your query, echo that out and run them all at once. If the same thing happens its probably a mysql timeout. Did my answer fail?

Comment: @Octopi I have not tried it yet, but I did get some evidence that you are correct because when I was running the script again it got about 80 more records updated before it conked out. I got the end result I needed using a different method.

Comment: @belinus Oh, ok.Could you tell me what that was please because I am curious.

Comment: @belinus , as far as I know, you'd have to write a piece of code which will update only few rows maybe 10,000 at a time, or maybe a 5,000 at a time, you can always use ```ini_set()``` function to set the time out to longer period of time, but I suggest you to do only few records at a time, and execute same script again and again.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to bump up your script time in `php.ini`, here I do it with a php function.
I think hex is more reliable as a key here, so I'm using that, since its always the same field length.
I've taken out its update since you dont change it.
Im also doing it with `mysql` `if` because I am sneaky.
Back up your db and give this a go.

```
set_time_limit(10000);
// SQL Server Login Info Removed
$sql_connection = new mysqli($sql_server, $sql_username, $sql_password, $sql_database);

if ($sql_connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection Failed: " . $sql_connection->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM coated";
$result = $sql_connection->query($query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $wrt_query = 
        "UPDATE coated SET 
         rgb=IF(rgb IS NULL or rgb='','".hex2rgb($row["hex"])."',rgb)', 
         hsl=IF(hsl IS NULL or hsl='','".hex2hsl($row["hex"])."',hsl)' 
         WHERE hex='".$row["hex"]."';";

        if ($sql_connection->query($wrt_query) === true) {
            echo "Record for " . $colorname . " updated <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record for " . $colorname . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```